# Can I steal from a city with a city wall?

Tags: catan-cities-and-knights

So I was playing the Cities & Knights scenario in the Catan app. On my turn, I rolled a seven. I moved the robber on the mountains hex where both of my opponents have a settlement and a city adjacent to it, as shown in the photo.

[image: Photo]

After I did that, the red player's settlement lights up, meaning I can steal from him. What I don't understand is, why did the green city not light up? I know that a city with a city wall adds 2 extra cards to your card limit, but I'm not quite sure that it also protects your cards when a player moves the robber on a hex adjacent to your walled city?

Comment: It is my understanding that walls have nothing to do with protection from being stolen from. The only reasons I can think of preventing stealing from a city/settlement adjacent to robber you placed is if the opponent has no cards to steal (doesn't appear that way in your screenshot) or house rules (e.g. can't block resource production of someone who hasn't yet scored).  You might check option settings to see if any such house rules are turned on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, you can steal from a player even if he has a city wall.**

The rules make no mention of a city wall having any effect on stealing from a player when the robber is moved. As you said, the only thing that the walls do is increase your hand limit by 2 for how many cards you can safely hold when a 7 is rolled.

I can't say why the green city did not light up; you would probably have to check with the app's support about that. But do you have any particular reason for thinking that it has to do with the city wall? If it is a bug in the app, that bug could be any number of things, including possibly the app treating a city wall as protection from getting stolen from.

Answer (score 1):

If your game has the "friendly robber" option selected, then you're not allowed to steal from anyone until they have more victory points than at the start of the game.